# Can't connect to MySQL Database on another PC on Local Network. [Windows]

Tags: mysql

**I am using MySQL 8 and I have recently come to need to access it from another PC on the same network.**

I have tried:

> - Granting all permissions to a new user and changing the host to '%'
> - Putting many different IPs and wildcards into 'bind_address' in the my.ini file.

Whilst doing the second thing (using bind_address) I realised that whenever I use a specific IP (such as 77.102.xx.xx OR 192.168.0.11) the MySQL service would not load up and would give this error:

> 2019-06-20T00:54:19.751327Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you
>   already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
>
> 2019-06-20T00:54:19.758702Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>
> 2019-06-20T00:54:21.241137Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld
>   8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Whenever I try to access the database from the other PC (using HeidiSQL) I get the following error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the mysql server to listen for network connections, easiest is to specify

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

That way it will accept connections on any IP address local to the system.

When accessing the mysql server remotely from another system you abviously need to specifiy which host to connect to; apparently you didn't and the default is to try to connect to a mysql server running locally, i.e. 127.0.0.1. I see it's very easy to specify the host using HeidiSQL. When using the `mysql` commandline client, you use the `--host=` parameter.

Comment: Well... thanks. I tried this yesterday and it didn't work and now it does, not really sure what's going on there, but thanks! Also If you are using MySQL 8, I think you should be using 'bind_address'.